# Running JavaScript inside ASP.NET Visual Basic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, html

I have a web application with jQuery and JavaScript,
I want to expand the webapp so it can do more,
But the features I want are supported in ASP.net VB,

But, I don't know if the JavaScript can be run after the vb.

Basically I want the web app to run in this sequence:

1. User enter the URL address,
   then
2. The ASP.net VB will do initialization process in `<script runat="server"></script>`
3. After the initialization process is done,
   the JavaScript will run in

`<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Is there a way for this to happen??

Comment: I have only a few times and not much, and most people say that they are running on a different side, but I thought that maybe there is a way in asp.net

Comment: What you are suggesting is the default behaviour. All scripts with `runat="server"` will happen first and then the server sends the output to the client. The client will then execute the scripts without `runat="server"`, in your case the javascript. I'd suggest putting the stuff that you run on the server into a CodeBehind, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

You should first read a little about the difference between [server side and client side](http://forums.asp.net/t/1368916.aspx/1).
Basically, the VB or C# (whichever you choose to work with) runs on the *Server Side* the JavaScript runs on the *Client Side* (e.g. inside the browser).

So what you want is basically the correct way to do things:

1. The page is created on the server side and sent to the client.
2. The client's browser can run the javascript on the [OnLoad](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) function .

**Note:** I recommend also reading about [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how server/client setups work by default.

ASP.NET (and other server-side languages) are really just pre-processors.  Based on the request a client sends (e.g. the querystring or form values), the server-side will perform some tasks (like saving to a DB), change some of the HTML output (like personalized styles), and return a *plain HTML* page back to the browser.

**EDIT**: Just to be clear, the VB is executed on the server and the javascript is executed after it gets back to the client.  You can execute javascript within VB if you want, but it is usually 1. unecessary, 2. inefficient, 3. will not produce the expected results.

Comment: I get it now, so my web app will execute the vb on the server side and then return the HTML&JavaScript to the browser -> what I want, and in my case I need the VB asp.net to accept files via synchronization from vb.net application from another computer using .net framework 4.5, after receiving the file then, the JavaScript will run ->using onload?

Comment: The javascript *will not* run on the server.  It will return the HTML page to whatever computer sent the file, and that computer will be responsible for executing the javascript (in the browser).  Javascript is designed to be a user-interface scripting language, so it needs to execute within a user-interface (ie the browser).